# Is this an Instantiation of Abstract Class?

Tags: java

> If Abstract class cannot be instantiated, then how can the variables
>   access and methods access of the abstract class A even without
>   extending is achieved in the class check (as you can see in the below
>   code)
>
> Is the created **a** an object of abstract class A?

**CODE**

```
    abstract class A
    {
        int a=10;
        public A()
        {
            System.out.println("CONSTRUCTOR ONE");
        }
        public A(String value)
        {
            System.out.println("CONSTRUCTOR "+value);
        }
        void add(int sum)
        {
            System.out.println("THE SUM IS:"+sum);
        }
        int sub(int a,int b )
        {
          return(a-b);
        }
    }

    public class check
    {
        public check()
        {
            new A("TWO"){};
        }
        public static void main(String args[]) 
        {
             int a,b,sum;
             a=10;
             b=15;
             sum=a+b;
             A s = new A() {};
             new check();
             s.add(sum);
             int subb=s.sub(35,55);
             System.out.println("THE SUB IS:"+subb);  
             System.out.println("THE VALUE OF A IS:"+s.a);
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
CONSTRUCTOR ONE
CONSTRUCTOR TWO
THE SUM IS:25
THE SUB IS:-20
THE VALUE OF A IS:10
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 7):

The `new A() {}` call creates an anonymous subclass and instantiates that. Since `A` does not contain any abstract methods, this works.

Comment: You can see this in action by calling s.getClass().getName(); it will return the name of the created anonymous subclass (usually something like A$1).

Answer (score 5):

You are creating subclass of A with this code -

```
A s = new A() {};
```

and here as well -

```
public check()
{
    new A("TWO"){};
}
```

Whereas, the normal syntax for instantiation is this -

```
A a = new A();
```

which would give compilation error if you try to run this code. As such, you don't have any abstract method in your class, and hence a nominal subclass suffices and you get your code executed.

HTH,
- Manish

Answer (score 1):

The normal use case is, you'd write `new MyAbstractClass(){` and then implement whatever abstract methods you need to implement (and/or override existing non-abstract methods), and the compiler will infer a non-abstract subclass for you. Since your class doesn't have any abstract methods, it's not necessary to override anything.

Answer (score 1):

`A` is marked abstract but has no abstract methods so when you do `new A() {}` you are providing an implementation that has nothing in it thus you are providing a concrete implementation and the class is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding "visibility" (public, private, package scope, etc)... you generally need a class instance to access class members.

An exception is static classes.

Otherwise, if you have an abstract base class, you'll need to subclass to get an instance.

In your case, however, the class isn't really "abstract" (despite your attempting to label it as such).  Simply because there are no abstract members or methods.

Answer (score 0):

`A s = new A() {};`
on the right side there is a new anonimus class which is inherited from A.
A class haven't abstract methods so in your new anonimus class you don't need to override any methods.

Answer (score 0):

- You created abstract class A **without** any abstract method.
- Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be **subclassed**.
- An **abstract method** is a method that is declared **without an implementation**.
- In the constructor check() you just created **anonymous class** and call constructor A(String value).

Answer (score 0):

```
new A("TWO"){};
```

This is a anonymous subclass  .
1. This class create and instantiate  at the same time...
2. No name of that class..
3. Because there is no name so it must need a parent .
You can get name by `s.getClass().getName();` which return `A$1`....